# Looking for the name of a distribution and/or a way to calculate its cumulative distribution function

Tags: distributions, effect-size, f-statistic, compound-distributions

For parameters $\nu_1$, $\nu_2$, $\lambda$, define random variables using a chi-squared distribution and a non-central chi-squared distribution:

$$
S \sim \chi^2_{\nu_2} / \nu_2
$$

$$
F \sim \frac{\chi^2_{\nu_1}(S\lambda) / \nu_1}{S}
$$

Here by $\chi^2_{\nu_2}$ I mean a central chi-squared distribution with $\nu_2$ degrees of freedom, and by $\chi^2_{\nu_1}(S\lambda)$ I mean a non-central chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu_1$ and noncentrality parameter $S$ times $\lambda$ (conditional on knowing the value of S).

**I am interested in the name of the distribution of $F$, if it has one, and if there is a fast way to calculate its cumulative distribution function.**

(My aim is to use this in a test to show, for example, that a linear model explains at least some amount of variance. It's an extension of the [TREAT](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/25/6/765/251641) test for t statistics to F statistics.)

(Note that this is similar but not identical to the usual non-central F distribution, which would be

$$
F \sim \frac{\chi^2_{\nu_1}(\lambda) / \nu_1}{S}
$$

and can be used for example to test values of Cohen's $f^2$, which is a *standardized* effect size. My aim is to have a test for an *unstandardized* effect size.)

**Edit:**

In terms of calculation, this R code works, but I would like it to be faster.

```
pf_noncentral_weird <- function(F, lambda, df1, df2) {
    func <- function(q) {
        s <- qchisq(q, df=df2)/df2
        pchisq(F*s*df1, df=df1, ncp=lambda*s)
    }

    integrate(func,0,1)$value
}
```

Comment: Because you are using the notation "$\chi^2_\nu$" in two obviously different senses -- first as a distribution and next as some kind of function -- please explain your notation.

Comment: I have updated the question to hopfeully be clearer. Both are meant to indicate distributions. In the first case a chi-squared distribution, and in the second case a non-central chi-squared distribution, with the non-centrality parameter in brackets.